# Fast scroll works for ListActivity without tabs but not ListFragment with tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-listfragment

I have a set of tabs, some of which can easily have over 100 rows. Setting `fastScrollEnabled` to true on the `ListView` element does not produce a fast scrollbar.

The ListViews for these tabs has `android:id="@+id/list_view"` so a scroll listener can be assigned to it to create infinite scrolling.

The rows for one of these tabs, when clicked, produces another `ListView` with over 35 elements, and the fast scrollbar works on it. It has `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

**My question is:** Does the `ListView being` inside a tab break the fast scrollbar or does the different id? If so, what needs to be done differently?

Code can be included if that would be more helpful. I just thought maybe this higher-level question might solve my problem.